# How keras.LSTM converts 3D input to 2D output?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, lstm

From keras's LSTM documentation the input should be A 3D tensor with shape (batch, timesteps, feature)

The output will be (batch, units) where units is number features we want from LSTM unit.

As my knowledge single cell of lstm takes hidden state, cell state and single number as input for timestamp t and passes it's output to next cell in form of c(t+1) and h(t+1). But from the documentation code it is generating output in 2D form?

```
inputs = np.random.random((32, 10, 8))
lstm = keras.layers.LSTM(4)
output = lstm(inputs)
output.shape
(32, 4)
```

Question 1: How vector representation is passed to LSTM? (At each timestamp it is passing 8 features. If there are 8 lstm units running in parallel then output should also be of size 8)

Question 2: How the final output is of size 4. (If we ignore batch size)

Comment: Your LSTM has 4 neurons, not 8, and by default return_sequence is set to False.

Comment: Yes Lstm has 4 neurons, but how is it handling vector representation of 8 features?

Comment: The number of neurons is unrelated to number of features.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like me, I found many people on Stackoverflow who are searching for the same answer on `keras.LSTM` and the answer to all those questions made me confused even more.

The problem is, that every article and video talks about basic LSTM which takes **one input per time** step but in the real world we we have a **vector representation**.

The complete flow of LSTM from input to output can be shown in the image below (which was my actual question)

[image]

Where in this case, the feature vector has a size of 3 and LSTM units have a size of 2 which makes input as `(batch_size, time_steps, 3)` and LSTM unit as `LSTM(units=2)`. An explanation of the image can be found [here](https://tung2389.github.io/coding-note/unitslstm) to clear your further doubts.

Answer (score 0):

LSTMs are compatible for the [basic artificial neuron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_neuron) architecture, so your input layer has 8 features which are fully connected to all 4 LSTM units in your output layer, hence in each time step your network is fed by a feature vector of size 8, produces an output of size 4, and each LSTM units are learning (among other things) a vector of size 8 to weigh your inputs.

LSTMs, or Recurrent Neural Networks (RNNs) in general, are usually fed by sequences of input vectors over time in each training step to make use of its hidden state. In your case the length of these sequences are 10. For each time step LSTM produces an output, but unless `return_sequences` is set to `True` for the [LSTM units](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/LSTM), only the last output is returned. Hence your output is of size 4 and not (10, 4) for each batch.

To deeper understand LSTMs, I recommend this reading: https://colah.github.io/posts/2015-08-Understanding-LSTMs/.
And in order to learn how to do time series forecasting by LSTMs using Tensorflow, I found this very useful: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/time_series.